# How to change page size depending on drop down?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently, I have a div container of this page section that contains 3 horizontal boxes that drop down when clicked on with more information. However, when any one of the boxes are clicked on, the last box is always a little cut off. The container of this page has a fixed size of around 100vh which fits the three boxes fine when none of them are clicked on. I could make the vh much higher to fix this issue, but there would be too much white space at the bottom when none of the boxes are clicked on. Hence, is there a way to "dynamically" increase the page size depending on when the boxes are clicked on and not clicked on.

Ex (what i want): Expanding (by clicking) box 2 increases page size from 100 vh to 120 vh to fit everything. Collapsing (by clicking again) box 2 decreases page size from 120 vh to 100 vh.

Github repo: https://github.com/robatras/Personal-Website
It happens in the interests section

Current view:

[image]

After clicking on one of the boxes:

[image]

Comment: use min-height: 100vh instead of height

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: I just tried that and it stayed the same, unfortunately.

Comment: You either need to secure the page height with whitespace or by expanded your content on opening a dropdrown. I would suggest an accordion solution instead since it pushes content down - which means the page will get bigger

Comment: Am i allowed to link my github repo? My index.html and style.css are fairly long

Comment: I edited my github repo in

Answer (score 0):

I have used jQuery to do this
Hope this will help you

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.maindiv div').on('click', function(){
        $('.maindiv div').css('height','100vh');
        $(this).css('height','120vh');
    });
});
```

```css
.maindiv{min-height:310vh; padding:10px; border: 2px solid gray;}
.maindiv .div1{height: 100vh; background-color: yellow;}
.maindiv .div2{height: 100vh; background-color: pink;}
.maindiv .div3{height: 100vh; background-color: green;}
```

```html
<div class="maindiv">
    <div class="div1">aa</div>
    <div class="div2">bb</div>
    <div class="div3">cc</div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```